# extract text between two strings bash sed excluding

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to extract some text between two strings (which appear only once in the file).

Suppose the file is,

```
....Some Data    
Your name is:

Dean/Winchester

You are male. Some data .....
```

I want to extract the text between 'Your name is:' and 'You are male.' both are unique and occur only once. 
So, the output should be,

```
Dean/Winchester
```

I tried using sed,

```
sed -n 's/Your name is:\(.*\)You are male./\1/' abcd
```

But it doesn’t output anything.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to remove the backslashes before the parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -n '0,/Your name is/ d; /You are male/,$ d; /^$/d; p' abcd
Dean/Winchester
```

For variety, here is an  `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '/Your name is/ {p=1; next} /You are male/ {exit} /^$/ {next} p==1 {print}' abcd 
Dean/Winchester
```

Comment: but the empty lines before and after 'Dean/Winchester' are coming in the output

Comment: @BrendenCarvalho I didn't understand that you also wanted to deleted the blank lines.  I will update.

Comment: @BrendenCarvalho Fixed.  Try it now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -n -e '/^Your name is:/,/^You are male/{ /^Your name is:/d; /^You are male/d; p; }' test 

Dean/Winchester
```